# Why do these two float64s have different values?

Tags: go, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Consider these two cases:

```
fmt.Println(912 * 0.01)
fmt.Println(float64(912) * 0.01)
```

([Go Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/k3OLoemaA8))

The second one prints 9.120000000000001, which is actually fine, [I understand why that is happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate).

However, why does the first line print 9.12, without the …01 at the end? Does Go multiply the two untyped constants and simply replace them with a 9.12 literal when compiling?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @asawyer Not really. OP is wondering why these two yield different results, not why one of the results is not exactly 9.12.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions):

> Constant expressions are always evaluated exactly; intermediate values and the constants themselves may require precision significantly larger than supported by any predeclared type in the language.

Since

```
912 * 0.01
```

is a constant expression, it is evaluated exactly. Thus, writing `fmt.Println(912 * 0.01)` has the same effect as writing `fmt.Println(9.12)`. When you pin `912` to `float64`, the other operand of the floating-point multiplication is implicitly pinned to `float64`, too. Thus, the expression `float64(912) * 0.01` behaves like `float64(912) * float64(0.01)`. 0.01 is not exactly representable in a `float64`, thus precision is lost in a different place than in the expression `float64(912 * 0.01)` which arises in the argument of `fmt.Println()` in your first example, explaining the different results.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for the different output is that in the first case `912 * 0.01` is the multiplication of 2 untyped constant values which is of arbitrary precision, and only the result is converted to `float64` when the value is passed to `Println()`. (See [Constant expressions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) section of the Language specification for details.)

In the second case `float64(912) * 0.01` first `912` is converted to `float64`, then the untyped constant `0.01` is converted to `float64` and these two values having `float64` are multiplied which is not an arbitrary precision, and will not give exact result.

**Note:**

In the first case the result will be converted to `float64` when passed to the `Println()`:

```
fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", 912 * 0.01, 912 * 0.01)
```

Output:

```
float64 9.12
```

[Test it on Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/26ZNgxcA9p)

Comment: "In the first case the result will be converted to `float64` when passed to the `Println()`" — you mean the result of multiplying two untyped constants, right?

Comment: @AttilaO. Yes, the result of the multiplication. When it is passed to the `Println()` function, it has to be converted to a typed value. Also edited to add code to show the type of the result.